# Searching for a user details (including custom fields) in People Administration Page

Tags: users, search

I want to search people on my people page in admin. I searched around and found this great plugin :-

[User search to People Admin](https://www.drupal.org/project/usersearchtoadmin) - This helps me search user through their email, usernames perfectly.

The only problem is that I want to search users through additional User fields I added later into the admin. As an example, each person has a Full Name as a custom field but this module is unable to search through it.

Any idea how I can achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).  With this you can create a searchable, sortable and filterable display using any format you desire, and including any fields you want.

> You need Views if
>
> You like the default front page view, but you find you want to sort it
>   differently. You like the default taxonomy/term view, but you find you
>   want to sort it differently; for example, alphabetically. You use
>   /tracker, but you want to restrict it to posts of a certain type. You
>   like the idea of the 'article' module, but it doesn't display articles
>   the way you like. You want a way to display a block with the 5 most
>   recent posts of some particular type. You want to provide 'unread
>   forum posts'. You want a monthly archive similar to the typical
>   Movable Type/Wordpress archives that displays a link to the in the
>   form of "Month, YYYY (X)" where X is the number of posts that month,
>   and displays them in a block. The links lead to a simple list of posts
>   for that month. Views can do a lot more than that, but those are some
>   of the obvious uses of Views.